# Error while creating aws_launch_template using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-auto-scaling

I am receiving an error while creating `aws_launch_template` using Terraform, below the error message
I am using an existing Role which is pre-created in the account

**Error message** - **An argument named "iam_instance_profile" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "iam_instance_profile"?**

Code

```
data "aws_iam_roles" "seamless_domain_join_role" {
  name = "seamless-domain-join-role"
}

data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "autoscale-instance-profile" {
  name = "seamless-domain-join-role"
}
```

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "Windows-instance" {
  name_prefix   = "Windows_Instance"
  image_id      = "ami-0526b9747c2c87a0b"
  iam_instance_profile = {
              arn = data.aws_iam_instance_profile.autoscale-instance-profile.arn
          }
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"
    tags = {
      Name : "sk-autoscaling-dj"
    }
  }
}
```

I am receiving same error with **name ** as well.

```
  iam_instance_profile = {
              name= data.aws_iam_instance_profile.autoscale-instance-profile.name
          }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `=` sign as that is a block not an argument:

```
iam_instance_profile {
  arn = data.aws_iam_instance_profile.autoscale-instance-profile.arn
}
```

This should really be clear from the provider documentation for `aws_launch_template` resource [1].

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#example-usage

Answer (score 0):

I see two mistakes in the code-

- The first one is  in-

```
data "aws_iam_roles" "seamless_domain_join_role" {
  name = "seamless-domain-join-role"
}
```

It should be `aws_iam_role` , rather than `aws_iam_roles` .

- The second mistake is in-

```
  iam_instance_profile = {
              arn = data.aws_iam_instance_profile.autoscale-instance-profile.arn
          }
```

It doesn't need a `=` as its a block.

The correct code is -

```
data "aws_iam_role" "seamless_domain_join_role" {
  name = "seamless-domain-join-role"
}

data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "autoscale-instance-profile" {
  name = "seamless-domain-join-role"
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "Windows-instance" {
  name_prefix = "Windows_Instance"
  image_id    = "ami-0526b9747c2c87a0b"
  iam_instance_profile {
    arn = data.aws_iam_instance_profile.autoscale-instance-profile.arn
  }
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"
    tags = {
      Name : "sk-autoscaling-dj"
    }
  }
}
```

`terraform validate`

`Success! The configuration is valid.`